# How to automatically update the Noda Time database, and how often?

Tags: .net, datetime, nodatime

How frequently do I need to update the Noda Time timezone database, and what are the steps to automatically update it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How frequently I need to update timezone database.

When it changes :)

You can find this out by fetching http://nodatime.org/tzdb/latest.txt which always contains the URL of the latest .nzd file.

Or if you don't need automation, subscribe to the `tz-announce@iana.org` mailing list (via the [IANA time zone home page](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)) - that contains an announcement for each release.

> What are the steps to automatically update the timezone database.

Download the latest .nzd file, then create a `TzdbDataSource` from it, [as documented in the user guide](http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/tzdb.html):

```
IDateTimeZoneProvider provider;
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(...))
{
    var source = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.FromStream(stream);
    provider = new DateTimeZoneCache(source);
}
```

That's assuming you're happy to wait for me to build the nzd file and upload it, of course. Alternatively, you can fetch the [latest source code](http://github.com/nodatime/nodatime), build the `NodaTime-All` solution and then run the `NodaTime.TzdbCompiler` utility yourself. This is easier now than it used to be, as you can just specify a URL to the latest .tar.gz file and the directory containing the CLDR files.

There isn't a simple way of updating `NodaTime.dll` itself to embed a new version of the tz database - basically it comes with whatever was current when it was built, and if you want something more recent you need to use the code above.